# night bus Helsinki Airport to Lappeenranta

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, night-transport, helsinki

im travelling to Lappeenranta arriving at the Helsinki airport. I couldn't find a Timetable for the buses, and would need some help..
My question is, if the buses go through the night, from Helsinki to Lappeenranta and also for the way back to the airport - cause I'm thinking of taking a flight back that would be quite early in the day (around 6am)
If someone could help me out, i would highly appreciate it! Thanks very much (:

Answer (score 5):

Pretty much all long distance buses in Finland should be listed in https://www.matkahuolto.fi/. Looking at Helsinki Airport or city center to Lappeenranta I can only see relatively few buses.

Lappeenranta is better served by train rather than bus. The trains can be found at https://www.vr.fi/. It looks like there are no trains at night either, so I think you are out of luck here.